# Apache druid No known server

Tags: java, druid

I am trying to setup the Apache Druid on a single machine following quickstart guide [here](http://druid.io/docs/0.12.0/tutorials/quickstart.html). When I start historical server, it shows  `io.druid.java.util.common.IOE: No known server` exception on screen.

Command:

```
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/historical/jvm.config xargs` \
-cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/historical:lib/*" \
io.druid.cli.Main server historical
```

Full stack-trace-

> 2018-04-07T18:23:40,234 WARN [main]
> io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils - Failed on try 1, retrying in
> 1,246ms. io.druid.java.util.common.IOE: No known server   at
> io.druid.discovery.DruidLeaderClient.getCurrentKnownLeader(DruidLeaderClient.java:276)
> ~[druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.discovery.DruidLeaderClient.makeRequest(DruidLeaderClient.java:128)
> ~[druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.fetchLookupsForTier(LookupReferencesManager.java:569)
> ~[druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.tryGetLookupListFromCoordinator(LookupReferencesManager.java:420)
> ~[druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.lambda$getLookupListFromCoordinator$4(LookupReferencesManager.java:398)
> ~[druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:63)
> [java-util-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:81)
> [java-util-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]     at
> io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.getLookupListFromCoordinator(LookupReferencesManager.java:388)
> [druid-server-0.12.0.jar:0.12.0]

I have tried to setup from scratch many times with exactly the same steps mentioned on quick-start guide, but I am unable to resolve this error. How to resolve this error?

Comment: I think you need to first start coordinator, overload and zookeeper before you start data server (historical)

Comment: Don't worry about the error. Start all the 5 services that would solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you already tried to start druid, then delete the `druid-X.Y.Z/log` and `druid-X.Y.Z/var` folders.

1. Start zookeeper `./zookeeper-X.Y.Z/bin/zkServer.sh start`
2. Recreate those folders you erased with `druid-X.Y.Z/bin/init`
3. Run each command in a new tab in this order

   ```
   java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/coordinator/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/coordinator:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server coordinator
   java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/overlord/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/overlord:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server overlord
   java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/broker/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/broker:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server broker
   java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/historical/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/historical:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server historical
   java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/middleManager/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/middleManager:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server middleManager
   ```

   You should now have 1 tab open for each of those commands (so 5).
4. Insert the data `curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/wikiticker-index.json localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task`

You will then see `{"task":"index_hadoop_wikiticker_2018-06-06T19:17:51.900Z"}`